# Saving as PNG-8 vs -24: How can I tell how much color info is being discarded?

Tags: png, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

Using Photoshop CS4 'Save for Web & Devices' -- I can tell with the Color Table how many colors are in use in the PNG-8, but am not sure how much downsampling to 256-colors is reducing the color depth of my image.

Cheers

Comment: The only way to know is to try it and look at the results.

Comment: Pretty subjective -- any tools out there that count colors in PNGs?

Comment: Counting colors won't help, as it won't tell you if the colors dropped are similar to the starting colors or not. You can subtract the 8-bit result from the original, but again it's going to be a subjective measure.

Comment: Try converting 24 to 8 and back to 24 then you can compare the results byte for byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure it with ImageMagick:

```
compare -mertic MSE original-input.png degraded-input.png difference-output.png
```

or with [DSSIM](https://github.com/pornel/dssim):

```
dssim original-input.png degraded-input.png difference-output.png
```

MSE is mean square error and DSSIM is structural (dis)similarity metric. The latter is a bit more closely aligned with human perception of image degradation, but both are just estimates.

Also when you convert images to 256-colors with latest version of [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) it will show MSE in verbose mode:

```
pngquant -v image.png
```